# JPA/SQL to get one week data

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa

I am trying to fetch one week's data comparing that with due column that I have. So I need to write a query that says if due is between currentdate of Monday + 7 days then fetch those records. I am currently using JPA connecting to Oracle DB. Since JPA also allows writing SQL query so trying either of the one.

First I tried

```
     select * from table  WHERE due_date >= CAST (DATEADD(day,7, GETDATE())AS Date);
```

After executing this query it says DATEADD is invalid

Since due date column is stored as Varchar2, timestamp across tables so first I need to convert

```
       to_date("yyyy-MM-dd") and then do the comparison.
```

I also tried

```
      due_date >= TO_DATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY); and says invalid.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATEADD` and `GETDATE` are not Oracle functions. Instead, add an `INTERVAL` to `SYSDATE` to get the equivalent of your current query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name 
WHERE  due_date >= SYSDATE + INTERVAL '7' DAY;
```

If you want it to be from midnight of the 7 days time (rather then the current time of day) then use `TRUNC` as well:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name 
WHERE  due_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '7' DAY;
```

> So I need to write a query that says if due is between currentdate of Monday + 7 days

If you want a query where the `due_date` is between the current date and Monday of next week then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name 
WHERE  due_date >= TRUNC( SYSDATE )
AND    due_date <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) + INTERVAL '7' DAY;
```

> Since `due_date` column is stored as Varchar2

Please, don't do that. If you are going to have a date value then store it as a `DATE` data type.

However, since you are storing it as an ISO8601 formatted string, you can convert the right-hand side of the comparison to a string and compare the values as strings (but better would be to use dates).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name 
WHERE  due_date >= TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
AND    due_date <  TO_CHAR(
                     TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) + INTERVAL '7' DAY,
                     'YYYY-MM-DD'
                   );
```

If you were to use `TO_DATE` to convert `due_date` from a string to a date then the query would also work; however, Oracle would not be able to use an index on the `due_date` column and to be able to use an index you would need a function-based index on `TO_DATE( due_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )` so converting the right-hand side is preferable (but still less preferable than having the column as a `DATE` data type and needing no conversions).

Comment: Should I do something like this  SELECT *
FROM   TABLE 1
WHERE  TO_DATE( due_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) > = TO_DATE( SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
AND    TO_DATE( due_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) <  TO_DATE(
                     TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) + INTERVAL '7' DAY,
                     'YYYY-MM-DD'
                   );       It says To_char is not valid and gives an option for to_date

Comment: SELECT *
FROM   TABLE 1
WHERE  to_date(due_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
AND    to_date(due_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') <  TO_CHAR(
                     TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) + INTERVAL '7' DAY,
                     'YYYY-MM-DD'
                   );----- It says literal does not match format string   and my due_date is 12-OCT-04

Comment: It is better to do date comparison right rather than string

Comment: In your first query you don't want to use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE` data type (like `SYSDATE`); if you fix that then it would work but, as I said in my answer, using `TO_DATE` on the column value would prevent you using an index on that column (and you would need a separate function-based index). The second query is wrong as you are mixing `TO_DATE` and `TO_CHAR` in the same comparison.

Comment: It is best to change your table to not store dates as `VARCHAR2` but to store them as the `DATE` data type. You aren't doing this so you either need to fix that or go for a second-best option which is either use string comparisons (which will work as you are using ISO8601 formatted dates) or convert everything to dates (but then you can't use an index).

Comment: When I say change the column to a `DATE`, I don't mean by using `TO_DATE`. I mean by using `ALTER TABLE` statements to create a new `DATE` column, migrate the data into it, drop the old `VARCHAR2` column and then rename the new column to take its place [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=54382de271519af9fbd821f69f6851de).